# Pullback on differentials of the 2-Sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

I'm considering the diffeomorphism of the 2-Sphere given by the antipodal map and the pullback given by this map on the differentials $d\theta$ and $d\phi$. Let $\psi$ be such a map. My intuition tells me that $\psi^*d\phi=-d\phi$ and the same for the pullback of $d\theta$. However, I am having trouble coming up with an explicit construction of $\psi$, and showing the results rigorously. First, is my intuition correct? And second how should this be constructed? I was thinking something along the lines of $(\theta,\phi)\to\left(\pi-\theta,\pi+\phi ~~(mod~~2\pi)\right)$. But this isn't going to work...any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only that 
$$\psi^* df = d  \psi ^* f = d (f\circ \psi)$$ 
for any function $f$. Now apply $f =\theta$ and $f = \phi$ to get

$$\psi^* d\theta = -d\theta \ \ \text{and } \ \ \psi^* d\phi = d\phi.$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So my construction for $\psi$ would be valid? Also, what's the reasoning behind $d\phi$ not picking up a minus? It seems that the rotation would do that, or am I getting confused by thinking about orthonormal vectors?

Comment: Actually that comes from your calculation $\psi (\phi) = \phi + \pi$ (mod $2\pi$). Think it this way, if both of them have a negative sign, then $\psi$ would orientation preserving and that imply $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is orientable  too. @TylerHG

Comment: Ah, that is enlightening. Thank you so much!